# Hybrid mobile app throws "Command failed with exit code 1" in Visual Studio 2015 in regards to Cordova for a remote build

Tags: macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

Recently I upgraded my components (Cordova, node.js, Ionic, etc.) on my Windows 10 computer and on my Mac in order to be (more or less) up-to-date.

Using Visual Studio 2015 I am developing a hybrid mobile app, which can be built when it comes to Android.

However when I start `remotebuild --secure false` on my Mac and try deploying the files from my Windows PC it finally fails with the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   /Users/joey/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.5.3/package/bin/create Command failed with exit code 1 MY-NICE-APP V4  C:\_develop\MY-NICE-APP_V4\MDAVSCLI 1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error /Users/joey/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.5.3/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1 -  MY-NICE-APP V4      1
```

The following has to be mentioned as well:

- Prior to the upgrade all went well.
- The way I deploy in Visual Studio is either 'Release - iOS - Remote Device' or 'Release - iOS - Simulator iPhone 5'. The error is the same.
- When deploying to Ripple locally all works well.
- On Mac I can see the commands `GET /cordova/build/tasks/21740 200 5.020 ms - 689` or similiar, which proves that the connection between Mac and PC works.
- In the target folder '/Users/joey/.taco_home/remote_builds/21740/cordovaApp' I see all files/folders, which have to be there. However the most important folder '(...)/cordovaApp/platforms' is empty.

I suspect a problem on my Mac in regards to Cordova, but am helpless what in detail.

Here are some config details regarding my Mac:

- node.js: 0.12.9
- npm: 2.14.9
- cordova: 6.5.0
- ios-sim: 6.1.2
- ionic: 2.2.1

Note that above Cordova shows something with 4.5.3, even I have a newer version running (6.5.0)...

Answer (score 0):

Having spent hours of debugging I fixed the issue by updating node.js, npm and remotebuild on my Mac. However I ran into a different problem, which I will describe in another thread.